# Error #224834. This directory, `/var/www/html/`, is not write enabled according to the server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am using Amazon AMI linux. And i am using Backupbuddy plugin to migrate from another domain to new domain which is hosted on AWS. I uploaded importbuddy php file and the necessary backup file using FTP when i visit the URL for migration i get the following error

> Error #224834. This directory, `/var/www/html/`, is not write enabled
>   according to the server. Please verify proper write permissions to
>   continue. If this persists, contact your web hosting provider and tell
>   them that is_writable("/var/www/html/") returns FALSE in PHP.

and i have checked the folder permission for **/var/www/html**  it is **ec2-user:ec2-user** and also all the files has 644 permissions and all the folder has 755

i don't have any clue why this error occurs any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/var/www/html/` should be owned `apache`, `apache2` or `httpd` user (not sure which one is in Amazon AMI) as which user apache daemon is started. You can check the username by exec:

```
ps -efl|grep httpd
```

and check the third column

EDIT: Based on the comment in AMI linux the user which run apache httpd daemon is `apache`

Comment: this is the output for the above command  http://pasted.co/6161c345

Comment: @PravinAlbie, As you can see the user is `apache`. So make the directory and files owned by this user

Comment: now it works perfectly